# Probability of drawing marbles with multiple draw options

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I have a bag with 60 marbles. 40 blue, 10 red and 10 green.
I will randomly draw 7 marbles.
If I draw a blue or a red marble I simply count them and take them out of the bag (no replacing).
If I draw a green marble, I get to withdraw it, then open the bag and also withdraw a red marble and count them. (essentially finding a green also finds me a red, removing two potentials from the bag).
What are the odds of of having 2 red marbles after 7 draws?

Is there an equation for this that describes this so I can change the variables?

I dont think I can use binomial probability equation because my p (probability of success on a single trial) is changing. Also because I may remove one or two marbles each pick, it is changing by a different amount each time.

My guess is I need to calculate the odds of withdrawing a red marble by either method and then do some form of summation?

Comment: [1] When you draw a red marble after a green marble, do you count it as one draw or two draws ? [2] What are your ideas on how to approach this problem ? You need to edit them in.

Comment: It looks as if you may be drawing without replacement, but it would be worth saying so.  Are you drawing one at a time, so doing your green/red thing in the middle of the draw, or do you take the extra reds after you have drawn all seven initial balls?

Comment: Drawing a green marble after a red counts as only one attempt but two marbles are then withdrawn. There is no replacement. You remove the red immediately after drawing a green, not at the end after the seventh draw. I hope this answers the questions. Also I have edited to attempt to make clearer.

Comment: It seems that without the extra removal, this is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution